# Zombies on starting resque & resque-scheduler

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debian, resque

Since upgrading my stack to Debian Squeeze, RVM 1.7.2, Ruby 1.9.2, and Rails 3.1rc6 (All gems are latest version) I see strange behavior: After rebooting the machine and starting redis/nginx etc. I start resque-scheduler with

```
rake resque:scheduler &
```

After that I'll start at least one worker with:

```
QUEUES=printing,mailing rake environment resque:work &
```

The moment I start one of these rake processes I get two zombies in my ps-list like this:

```
1222 pts/3    Sl     0:12 resque-scheduler-2.0.0.d: Schedules Loaded
1236 pts/3    Z      0:00 [ruby] <defunct>
```

This in itself is only a cosmetic issue, but resque and it's web front end don't behave like expected any more; e.g. I can only see some of the workers as active and working in the web front end.

Any ideas on how to make resque behave itself again?

Comment: Seems I got it. I integrated NewRelic RPM as gem 'rpm_contrib', '>= 2.1.4.beta' and gem 'newrelic_rpm' to log what happens in the resque workers. The problem vanished once I removed the 'rpm_contrib' gem from my Gemfile.

Comment: In order to help you more I would need to see your two rake tasks. Also I would like to know what version of resque you are using seeing how it does effect how workers are started and stopped. As for the cosmetic can you please provide more information on exactly what the resque web-UI is reporting. I found that resque Web-UI has a complicated way of reporting and monitoring workers.